# How to automatically save attachment from specific sender?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I would like to automatically save attachments from a specific sender in a predetermined folder.

```
Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set objInboxItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
   Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
   Dim strSenderAddress As String
   Dim strSenderDomain As String
   Dim objAttachment As Attachment
   Dim strFolderPath As String
   Dim strFileName As String

   If Item.Class = olMail Then
      Set objMail = Item

      'Get sender domain
      strSenderAddress = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
      'strSenderDomain = Right(strSenderAddress, Len(strSenderAddress) - InStr(strSenderAddress, "@"))

      'Change to the specific domain as per your needs
      If strSenderAddress = "Da.Te@union.de" Then
         If objMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            For Each objAttachment In objMail.Attachments
                'Change the folder path where you want to save attachments
                strFolderPath = "U:\Test"
                strFileName = objMail.Subject & " " & Chr(45) & " " & objAttachment.FileName
                objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFolderPath & strFileName
            Next
         End If
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

This code is from [here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/how-to-auto-save-all-attachments-from-senders-in-a-specific-domain-via-outlook-vba/), with minor modifications.

Comment: What "isn't working"? Did you "Change to the specific domain as per your needs" and "Change the folder path where you want to save attachments" when you copied this?

Comment: I get the error message : Compile error: Only valid in object module...

Comment: Have you tried moving it to an object module, i.e. `ThisOutlookSession`?

Comment: Yes I get the same error :-(

Comment: That's not possible. That compile error is referring to the `WithEvents` keyword, which is illegal in a standard/procedural module; you can only use it in a class module, which `ThisOutlookSession` is (it's a *document* module, owned by Outlook - by definition it's a class). You're not telling us the whole story! =)

Comment: I tried the Code in an new class module, it is not working. I get no error but it does not save the fieles

Comment: My issue was that I hadn't enabled Macros in the trust center, otherwise your code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

*How about the following... Remember to restart Outlook*

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim Filter As String
        Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail" & _
                           Chr(34) & " Like '%Da.Te@union.de%' And " & _
                           Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & _
                           Chr(34) & "=1"

    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
End Sub



Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

        Dim FilePath As String
            FilePath = "C:\Temp\"

        Dim AtmtName As String
        Dim Atmt As attachment

        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            AtmtName = FilePath & Atmt.filename
            Atmt.SaveAsFile AtmtName
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

> *<sub>**[Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)** Occurs when one or more items are added to the specified collection. **This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once**. This event is not available in Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript).</sub>*

---

> <sub>***[Items.Restrict method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396http://)*** is an alternative to using the Find method or FindNext method to iterate over specific items within a collection. The Find or FindNext methods are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The Restrict method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.</sub>

---

> <sub>**[Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867646.aspx#String%20Comparisons%20Using%20DASL%20Syntax)** that DASL filters support includes equivalence, prefix, phrase, and substring matching. Note that when you filter on the Subject property, prefixes such as "RE: " and "FW: " are ignored.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Code ! Should I paste the Code in the "ThisOutlookSession" Module , a Standard new Modul or a new class module ?

Comment: @0m3r What is better about your code vs OP's Code? Yours seems harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything was wrong with your posted code, I too was looking to use that code but not to filter by domain, but specific sender. I tweaked the code a bit for my needs and made it easier to tweak for a new user by moving the 3 fields needing to be modified to the top. I also commented out the part that saved the attachment prefixed with "Subject - Attachmentname" so it saves it purely as "Attachmentname".

My issue was I hadn't enabled Macros in the Trust Center and I had it in a separate Module but it must be under "ThisOutlookSession".

I also added a line to delete the message after saving attachment.

[image]

```
Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set objInboxItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
   Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
   Dim strSenderAddress As String
   Dim strSenderDomain As String
   Dim objAttachment As Attachment
   Dim strFolderPath As String
   Dim strFileName As String
   Dim strDesiredSender As String
   Dim strDesiredDomain As String

   strFolderPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\"
   'strDesiredDomain = "gmail.com"
   strDesiredSender = "user@gmail.com"

   If Item.Class = olMail Then
      Set objMail = Item

      'Get sender domain
      strSenderAddress = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
      strSenderDomain = Right(strSenderAddress, Len(strSenderAddress) - InStr(strSenderAddress, "@"))

      'Use either strSenderDomain or strSenderAddress Depending on Filter Desired
      'If strSenderDomain = strDesiredDomain Then
      If strSenderAddress = strDesiredSender Then
         If objMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            For Each objAttachment In objMail.Attachments
                ''''Save in format "Subject - Attachmentname"
                'strFileName = objMail.Subject & " " & Chr(45) & " " & objAttachment.FileName
                'objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFolderPath & strFileName 
                ''''Save in format exactly as attachment name
                objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFolderPath & objAttachment.FileName 
                objMail.Delete 'Delete after saving attachment
            Next
         End If
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```